# error while npm start - Undefined variable: "$grid-row-columns" in \node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid-framework.scss (line 37, column 30)

Tags: css, node.js, angular, sass, angular-builder

**I am getting ERROR in**

```
./src/styles/theme/bootstrap.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles/theme/bootstrap.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
```

undefined ^Undefined variable:

```
"$grid-row-columns".
      in {path}\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid-framework.scss (line 37, column 30)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may need to upgrade or downgrade your version of bootstrap. It's hard to tell without seeing your current project setup. May be something to do with the `sass-loader`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the solution. I downgraded bootstrap to the version 4.3.1